# Who is this guy : Z.A. Melzak (wrote Companion to Concrete Mathematics) ?

Tags: gm.general-mathematics, teaching

*Author* : Z.A. Melzak
*Book Title* : Companion to Concrete Mathematics.
*Publication* :  Dover renewed 2004 2 volumes in one. Copyright 1972/1976.

I found this book extremely nice.
To whet your appetite he talks about reification as well as some plain and less plain way to accelerate series convergence. 
In a few words it is a rare blend of concreteness and conceptualization. It smells a bit like Concrete Mathematics (by Knuth and co..) but the
only information I found was an an depth review by Klamkin (not entirely positive though).

QUESTION : I would like to find connections : information about the author, and for those who appreciate this book or heard loadably about it: what others books/works are in the same vein ?

Comment: Is this a reasonable MO question?

Comment: No. But it's a terrific book. 

Comment: @Mariano According to Overflow requirements , this is a very specific question, tough it asks for soft information , this very information is sparse ( otherwise I guess I would have found some). Moreover his maths are "written" which is rare. May be the answer will tell that he was a loner with very little mathematical collaboration (publicized).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to [the Mathematics Genealogy Project](http://genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=17764), Zdzislaw Alexander Melzak did his graduate studies at MIT and became a professor at UBC. I'm not sure whether his name might have actually been spelled Zozislaw, though (I guess someone Polish would know which is correct). The UBC Library has online [a photo of him](http://sproat.library.ubc.ca/cdm4/item_viewer.php?CISOROOT=/ubcnew&CISOPTR=3385&CISOBOX=1&REC=1) from 1966.

Comment: Google gives approximately four million hits for Zdzislaw and about ten thousand for Zozislaw.  I'd bet that the d-spelling is correct, and that the o-spelling at the UBC library is an example of "the more difficult reading is the stronger" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lectio_difficilior_potior) applied to an English speaker transcribing a Polish name.

Comment: Yes, the correct spelling is Zdzislaw. The "dz" here is pronounced by Poles roughly as "g" in "gym." Wikipedia has something to say on this name: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zdzis%C5%82aw

Comment: Actually I found some other inofrmation : he is the author of a book called In search of the Fulcrum" literary autobiographical. And also a book called "Bypasses: A Simple Approach to Complexity" 